# Request Github API to create a repository with R

Tags: r, github

I wrote some code to create a repository on Github using the Github API using R. I have the authentication working properly, and I can do things like request the repositories and things like this....but when it comes to create a repository, I get always status `400` and as a message `Problems parsing JSON`.

This is the code I use to authenticate (you need to change your app and secret numbers):

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)

# 1. Find OAuth settings for github:
#    http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/
oauth_endpoints("github")

# 2. Register an application at https://github.com/settings/applications
#    Insert your values below - if secret is omitted, it will look it up in
#    the GITHUB_CONSUMER_SECRET environmental variable.
#
#    Use http://localhost:1410 as the callback url
myapp <- oauth_app("TestApp", "app-number","secret-number")
scope <- 'public_repo'
# 3. Get OAuth credentials
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"),scope=scope, myapp)
```

And here I do the request to create a new repo, based on the documentation here: 
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

```
#Push repository to Github
url = "https://api.github.com/user/repos"
data = list("name"= "newRepo")
r<-POST(url,body = data,config(token = github_token))
content(r)
```

Anyone with some experience with this can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the **encode = "json"**, it will do the trick.

```
r <- POST(url,body = data, encode = "json", config(token = github_token))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the (impressive) [git2r](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=git2r) package and interface the GitHub API directly *in native code*.

It allows for all git transformation on a local repo, and (by using ssh) also allows you to connect and authenticate against the remote side.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about git2r....I will use it for something else it is just what I needed! :-)