# Delete Github organization repo in R using the REST API

Tags: r, git, api, github, httr

Following the instructions on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177894/request-github-api-to-create-a-repository-with-r) SO question I was able to create a repo for an organization that I own using the GitHub REST API and the R packages `httr` and `RCurl`. Now, I'm having issues deleting the repo using the API.

I created an OAuth app on GitHub and gave the app access to my organization. Then I ran the code below to create a token with the `delete_repo` scope.

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)

# 1. Find OAuth settings for github:
#    http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/
oauth_endpoints("github")

# 2. Register an application at https://github.com/settings/applications
#    Insert your values below - if secret is omitted, it will look it up in
#    the GITHUB_CONSUMER_SECRET environmental variable.
#
#    Use http://localhost:1410 as the callback url
myapp <- oauth_app("TestApp", "app-number","secret-number")
scope <- 'delete_repo'
# 3. Get OAuth credentials
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"),scope=scope, myapp)
```

Per the GitHub API v3 developer guide, the URL to [**create**](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) a new repo in an organization is

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos
```

Using this URL I was able to create a private repo for my organization named 'Reliability' by running:

```
#Push repository to Github
url_c = "https://api.github.com/orgs/Reliability/repos"
data = list("name"= "newRepo", "private" = "true")
POST(url = url_c, body = data, config(token = github_token))
```

To [**delete**](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository) a repo, the developer guide states that the URL should be of the form

```
DELETE repos/:owner/:repo
```

For an organizational repo, I interpret that this URL should be

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos/:owner/:repo
```

However, when I run the following code I get a response of `404` not found.

```
# Delete repository from Github organization
url_d = "https://api.github.com/orgs/Reliability/repos/Auburngrads/newRepo"
DELETE(url = url_d, config(token = github_token))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The wording in the GitHub developer guide is misleading with respect to URL that should be used to delete organizational repos using the REST API.

The developer guide states that to [**delete**](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository) a repo, the URL should be of the form

```
DELETE repos/:owner/:repo
```

However, for an organizational repo, the URL should be of the form

```
DELETE repos/:org/:repo
```

I was able to successfully delete a repo from my organization called 'Reliability' by 1) ensuring that my app token had the appropriate `delete_repo` scope and 2) running the following code

```
# Delete repository from Github organization
url_d = "https://api.github.com/repos/Reliability/newRepo"
DELETE(url = url_d, config(token = github_token))
```